# How to heat a small enclosure using resistors; how many amps/ohms should the relay be?

Tags: relay, resistance, heat, watts

I have a plastic case that I plan on heating with resistors. Temperatures could drop down to -40°F or possibly lower in an outdoor location.

The only power that would be available is solar or two 12 V batteries, 10 Ah each in parallel for 20 Ah. I found an online calculator where you can input your case material, the dimensions, temperature, etc. This tells you how many watts of heat you would need to heat to the temperature.

So for -40°F and to warm to say 34°F or around there, you would need 180 W. I did some calculations but it seems off to me, maybe there is a better way to do this but I calculated having 12 20-24 Ω, 30 W resistors in parallel. I plan to have it shut off once it reaches a certain temperature and turn on when the temp is too low.

I still have not done the calculations on how long the battery would last and how to keep it sort of self-charged since there is no main line for the box. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What material is the enclosure made from?  Adding some insulation (either internal or external), or even having thicker walls could drastically reduce your heating requirements (at the expense of making your box operate hotter in normal or high temperature environments).

Comment: 180W seems pretty high for a plastic enclosure, unless it's fairly large or has thin walls.

Comment: 180W is 15A @ 12V.  Using fully charged 20Ah batteries, you will only be able to keep that up for 1 hour and 20 minutes maximum, but probably less in reality.  If that -40 temperature is occurring at night and your intention is to keep the box warm till morning, you won't make it through.

Comment: Your resistor calculations might be off.  (12V)^2 / 20 ohms = 7.2W.  You would need 25 of those (not 12) to equal 180W.

Comment: You might consider how near-space balloon payloads are insulated and heated, e.g., https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/58400 and https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/188 . With sufficient insulation, little or no heat should be needed.

Comment: @user4574 the material is polypropylene, this might sound crazy but I plan to use Rockwool for insulation under some sheet metal. The 180W might be too high, I was basing it off of raising the temp from under -40 closer to -50 to 34 or so but I am not sure how long it would stay above  34 degrees though I might not need to even do that as long as I am not recharging the battery below 32F.  The case is (37.2 x 26 x 15.5 cm). This is how I calculated the 180w . https://www.powerstream.com/temperature-rise-in-an-electronics-enclosure.htm

Comment: @user4574 I was also using this as a guide for calculating the resistors but the numbers did seem off with the 180w. https://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/08/02/arduino-heater-1/ I planned to use a relay instead of the transistor though.

Comment: @user4574 my original thought was to use 4 150ohm 2-3amp resistors and a relay but after thinking about it, I think it would not heat it enough.

Comment: @gitrinec My first thought was that you'd need to include Stefan-Boltzmann. Then I looked at your 'calculator' website and saw that it completely neglects this. Yet it can have a significant impact on results. (This is why 'space blankets' work and may save lives.) Inside the box everything is essentially just a black body radiator. So radiation calcs are easy for the interior. But the outside surface that radiates into its environment? If you want to keep the heat inside, then lower the exterior surface emissivity as much as possible.

Comment: Can you do some testing? 180W seems high by maybe an order of magnitude. A lot will depend on insulation, how wires get in and out and so on. Of course if it is *too* well insulated it may cook itself to death (or to poor reliability/calibration) when the ambient is at the other extreme, just form irreducible internal power dissipation.

Comment: If it's not too expensive, it might be worth it to just buy the box itself, put a load in it of known wattage (like a resistor), and measure the temperature rise.  That's useful information to know before you get too far into the design and spend money on more expensive stuff like batteries and such.

Comment: @user4574 I plan to do some testing this coming week, I have the box already. I will update once I test and see how the test goes.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, I  plan on testing this coming week. I will update you after testing. I think that with other electrics running I won't need a full 180w to dissipate.